# What is the usage of var (local variable) in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
> var v = Math.random() // var means local variable
> v
0.012659968143515665
> w = Math.random()
0.055781313840123414
```

What is the key difference between the variable v and w? Scope?
In other words, when should I use local variables and when I should not?

I am focused on MongoDB interactive shell environment and it's usage with Python too.

Answer (score 1):

The scoping rules in the `mongo` shell are the same as in any JavaScript environment, see [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope).

This means, for example, that any variable declared (or used the first time) without `var` will be put in the global scope.

If you're writing scripts to execute with the `mongo` shell (e.g. `mongo path/to/script.js`) there is almost no reason to ever declare a variable without `var`, but if you're just typing stuff into the shell it doesn't matter. Typing `var` is just extra work for no gain.